# R data.table keyby multiple columns when chaining

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a new data table with just two columns and join it with another table using these two columns as keys. I could do this:

```
a.dt <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 2:4)
setkey(a.dt,x,y)
key(a.dt)
# [1] "x" "y"
# ...(join)
```

But I don't want to use `setkey` - I want to chain immediately into the join, i.e. after creating the table I want to `keyby` both new variables. For a reason that is not clear to me I'm getting this error:

```
a.dt <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 2:4)[, .SD, keyby = .(x,y)]
# Error in jsub[[ii]] : attempt to select less than one element
```

This is my ugly workaround

```
a.dt <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 2:4, z = 3:5)[, .SD, keyby = .(x,y)][,z := NULL]
key(a.dt)
# [1] "x" "y"
```

Can somebody explain why I can't `keyby` both variables? Am I doing something fundamentally silly?

Edit: for completeness adding session info

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
# [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

# other attached packages:
# [1] data.table_1.9.4 plyr_1.8.2       foreign_0.8-63  

# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] magrittr_1.5   tools_3.2.1    reshape2_1.4.1 Rcpp_0.12.0    stringi_0.4-1  stringr_1.0.0  chron_2.3-45
```

Comment: Your code had `setkey(a.dt,...)` before `a.dt` was defined. Figured that was a typo..?

Comment: `data.table(x = 1:3, y = 2:4, key = c("x","y"))` Something like what you're proposing has been discussed before, and the consensus seems to be that the new feature `on=` addresses it: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/794

Comment: Thank you, I missed this simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for editing with `sessionInfo()`. `1.9.4` is ~ an year old and there's been several bug fixes and features implemented in the recently released `v1.9.6` (>180 issues closed). So please upgrade.

Comment: Upgrading "as we speak" :-). Very much appreciate the "on" feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can key while creating a *data.table* using the `key` argument:

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.6
DT2 = data.table(x=3:4, y=4:5, w=5:6)
DT1 = data.table(x=1:3, y=2:4, z=7:9, key=c("x", "y"))[DT2]
```

Alternatively, from `v1.9.6` on you can use the `on=` argument to specify the columns on which the join should be performed.

```
DT2 = data.table(a=3:4, b=4:5, w=5:6)
DT1 = data.table(x=1:3, y=2:4, z=7:9)[DT2, on=c(x="a", y="b")]
```

Another way is to use `setDT()` on a *list* along with the `key` argument.

```
DT2 = data.table(a=3:4, b=4:5, w=5:6)
DT1 = setDT(list(x=1:3, y=2:4, z=7:9), key=c("x", "y"))[DT2]
```

---

`dt[, .SD, keyby=.(x, y)]` returns an *empty data.table* for me (as it should). Not sure which version of data.table you're using. This is because `.SD` by default gets assigned all columns *except the columns mentioned in `by=`*. Since there are two columns, and you've provided both to group by, `.SD` is empty. Therefore an empty data.table is returned. If you really want this behaviour, you'll need to explicitly set `.SDcols` as follows:

```
dt[, .SD, keyby=.(x, y), .SDcols=c("x", "y")]
# or from v1.9.6 we can also do
dt[, .SD, keyby=.(x, y), .SDcols=x:y]
```

But note that this'll return `x,y` twice.

Comment: Thank you Arun, this answers my question completely.

Comment: Heh, sorry about that. My "more substantive" edit added one char; and Jaap's, seven :)